# List all Entities of single Datastore Kind using GetMulti

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way for me to use datastore's GetMulti, or another function built into the "[appengine/datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference)" package, to get all entities of a single kind?

For instance, I have a kind "Queue" with many entities that have two to three properties. Each entity has a unique stringID and what I'm trying to get is a slice or other comparable data type of each unique stringID.

The purpose of Queue is to store some metadata and the unique key names that I'll be looping over and performing a cron task on (e.g. keys "user1", "user2", and "user3" are stored as kind Queue, then - during cron - are looped over and interacted with).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to Google App Engine and I didn't read the documentation before diving in. Now that I actually read the docs, it looks like I'll be answering my own question. This can be accomplished via a simple query, looping over the Keys, and appending the StringID of each key to a slice of strings:

```
var queuedUsers []string

q := datastore.NewQuery("Queue").KeysOnly()
keys, _ := q.GetAll(c, nil)
for _, v := range keys {
    queuedUsers = append(queuedUsers, v.StringID())
}
```